# linq группировка с условием

Tags: c#, linq

есть 3 значения bool, в зависимости от которых надо или не надо группировать по соответствующим полям. например:

```
    bool b1, b2, b3;

    var v = list
        .GroupBy(
        g => new 
        {  
            g.c0,

            //здесь не понятно!...
            b1 == true ? g.c1 : //do nothing !! ничего здесь не делать !!!!,
            b2 == true ? g.c2 : //do nothing !! ничего здесь не делать !!!!...
        })
        .Select(
        s => new
        {
            p0 = s.Key.c0,
            p1 = b1 == true ? s.Key.c1 : s.FirstOrDefault().c1,
            p2 = b2 == true ? s.Key.c2 : s.FirstOrDefault().c2//...
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: т.е. надо отфильтровать ненужные значения? напишите пример. есть такие-то данные и надо получить такой-то результат.

Comment: надо сгруппировать по нескольким полям, или по одному. если b1 == true, группировать по соответствующему полю, если нет - ничего не делать (проверить следующее условие, или сгруппировать только по одному полю (которое группируется всегда))

Comment: понятно. не обязательно все делать в одну строку. можно так `1. var lst = items;  2. if(b1) { lst = items.groupby(...); }` -- т.е. на строке 1. вы создаете коллекцию. а в строке 2. проверяете. и если надо - группируете.

Comment: допустим что b1, b2, b3 это настройки пользователя, по которым группируется коллекция

Comment: разве нельзя это уместить в одну строку?

Comment: _"допустим что b1, b2, b3 это настройки пользователя, по которым группируется коллекция"_ -- значит у вас будет. var lst = items;  а дальше три условия.  if(b1) lst = lst.groupBy(...);     дальше if(b2) lst = lst.groupBy(...); и т.д.

Comment: не хотелось лишний раз бегать по коллекции

Comment: _"разве нельзя это уместить в одну строку?"_ -- можно. но можно и не в одну.

Comment: хотелось в одну, вы знаете как?

Comment: _"не хотелось лишний раз бегать по коллекции"_ -- там один проход будет. функции просто складываются в цепочку.

Comment: _"хотелось в одну, вы знаете как?"_ -- без проверочных данных, на которых можно протестировать код - не получится нормальный ответ. поэтому добавьте в вопрос проверочные данные. хотя бы минимум.. что есть и что хотите получить.

Comment: я же нарисовал примерный запрос. осталось поменять только //здесь не понятно и следующие две строки. они были для примера как хочу, понятно что так работать не будет

Comment: хотелось избежать сильно дублирующегося кода

Comment: как вариант использовать `DynamicLinq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена следующим образом:

```
bool b1, b2, b3;

var v = list
    .GroupBy(
    g => new 
    {  
        c0 = g.c0,
        c1 = b1 ? g.c1 : null,
        c2 = b2 ? g.c2 : null
    })
    .Select(
    s => new
    {
        p0 = s.Key.c0,
        p1 = b1 ? s.Key.c1 : s.FirstOrDefault().c1,
        p2 = b2 ? s.Key.c2 : s.FirstOrDefault().c2
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: обратите внимание что `FirstOrDefault` может вернуть `null` и тогда все упадет, поэтому стоит добавить какую-нибудь проверку

Comment: @Grundy так вроде вернёт значение по умолчанию для данного типа, разве не так? вообще у меня стоят проверки при получении коллекции из базы, на уровне записи в DataTable (использую ADO)

Comment: тут важно что за провайдер вы используете, а именно что за объект `list`. Ну и значение по умолчанию для ссылочных объектов - `null`

Comment: list это List<Item>. Item содержит типы string, int, decimal и DateTime. вы имеете ввиду если там попадётся ссылка на другой объект в самом Item?

Comment: я имел ввиду вариант, когда `s` окажется пустым, так как в `s` хранятся `item` то `s.FirstOrDefault()` вернет `null`

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего, наверное, создать `IEqualityComparer`.

Например, пусть тип данных, который вы группируете, такой:

```
public class Data
{
    public string c1;
    public int c2;
}
```

Тогда определим параметрический `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class DataKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Data>
{
    bool b1, b2;

    public DataKeyComparer(bool b1, bool b2)
    {
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
    }

    public bool Equals(Data x, Data y)
    {
        return
            (b1 ? (x.c1 == y.c1) : true) &&
            (b2 ? (x.c2 == y.c2) : true);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Data x)
    {
        var result = 0;
        if (b1) result = result * 13 + x.c1.GetHashCode();
        if (b2) result = result * 13 + x.c2.GetHashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Теперь сравнивать получается просто:

```
var grouped = data.GroupBy(d => d, new DataKeyComparer(b1, b2)).ToList();
```

---

У этого решения есть недостаток: значения `b1` и `b2` проверяются каждый раз, хотя можно было бы просто создать нужный компаратор один раз.

Для этого воспользуемся CodeDom. На основе класса `DataKeyComparer` несложно создать динамически класс, реализующий нужное сравнение, из исходника.

```
static IEqualityComparer<Data> CreateComparer(bool b1, bool b2)
{
    var literalCode =
        "using <вставьте тут ваше пространство имён, в котором лежит класс Data>;\n" +
        "using System.Collections.Generic;\n" +
        "public class DataKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Data>\n" +
        "{\n" +
        "    public bool Equals(Data x, Data y)\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        return\n" +
        (b1 ? "            (x.c1 == y.c1) &&\n" : "") +
        (b2 ? "            (x.c2 == y.c2) &&\n" : "") +
        "            true;\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "    public int GetHashCode(Data x)\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        var result = 0;\n" +
        (b1 ? "        result = result * 13 + x.c1.GetHashCode();\n" : "") +
        (b2 ? "        result = result * 13 + x.c2.GetHashCode();\n" : "") +
        "        return result;\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}\n";

    var compilationResult =
        new CSharpCodeProvider()
                .CompileAssemblyFromSource(
                    new CompilerParameters()
                    {
                        GenerateInMemory = true,
                        GenerateExecutable = false,
                        ReferencedAssemblies = { typeof(Data).Assembly.Location }
                    }, literalCode);

    if (compilationResult.Errors.HasErrors)
        throw new Exception("Compilation failed:\n" +
            string.Join("\n", compilationResult.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>()));

    var type = compilationResult.CompiledAssembly.GetType("DataKeyComparer");
    return (IEqualityComparer<Data>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Использовать так же:

```
var grouped = data.GroupBy(d => d, CreateComparer(b1, b2)).ToList();
```

Функция `CreateComparer` довольно тяжёлая, поэтому имеет смысл применять её лишь при достаточно больших размеров списка и кэшировать её результат. (И профилировать, профилировать!)

---

Для случая, когда количество полей небольшое (2-3), имеет смысл не напрягаться, а просто создать 4 или там 8 компараторов вручную, и выбирать нужный из них. Кодогенерация интересна как самостоятельное упражнение, и оправдывает себя по сути лишь когда вы упираетесь в нескалируемость ручного создания компараторов.

Comment: `SO25.Data` - это так и задумано? :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Тьфу, недоредактировал! :)

Comment: Что-то мне кажется с кодедом как-то слишком усложнено все

Comment: @Grundy: А как было бы проще?

Comment: вообще в DynamicLinq - это уже реализовано, ну и мне кажется через ExpressionTree было б проще, но тут конечно еще вопрос :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Круто, не знал насчёт DynamicLinq. Напишете ответ с примером? С ExpressionTree, по идее, тоже должно получиться, если подгонять проекцию, а не EqualityComparer (но такое решение по идее медленнее за счёт лишних сравнений).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35092/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).

Comment: @VladD спасибо за подробный ответ!! сейчас собираюсь сделать EqualityComparer, но как быть с конструкцией select()? там тоже должна быть проверка - подставлять s.Sum(ss => ss.FieldName) или s.FirstOrDefault().FieldName

Comment: @bmo: С `Select`'ом как раз проще. Вы пишете что-то такое: `var fieldNames = s.Select(ss => ss.FieldName);` и затем в зависимости от условий `var result = условие ? fieldNames.Sum() : fieldNames.FirstOrDefault();`.

Comment: @VladD я уже думал об этом, но не вызовет ли это построчную проверку условия? видел примеры использования DynamicLinq в частности метода Select. Но необходимо создать свой обобщённыйй метод Select, наследованный от какого-то класса. к сожалению уже потерял вкладки, но использовать можно как-то так list.Select<Item>(s => s, "new { a1 = s.Field.Sum(), a2 = ....... }"). всё для того что бы строго типизировать результат, потому что DynamicLinq не поддерживает обобщённые типы.

Comment: я могу что-то не понимать, но вы об этом уже разговаривали выше в чате. всё-же больше всего волкнует вопрос производительности всёх этих решений... или ваше решение, или DynamicLinq (что выглядет несомненно легче). такой if из вашего комментария в Select'е будет единовременно проверен?

Comment: @bmo: нет, построчную проверку это не вызовет. У вас есть ленивый, то есть невычисленный, набор fieldNames, когда вы говорите .FirstOrDefault(), он начинает вычисляться, и после первого элемента останавливается.

Comment: @bmo: Под `if` вы имеете в виду тернарный оператор? Да, он будет вызван один раз на весь большой `Select`.

Comment: @Vlad да, тернарный оператор. я имею ввиду каждую строку получаемой коллекции (new Item { ... })

Comment: @bmo: Я не вполне понял, как именно вы собираетесь использовать `Select`. Нужен код. В любом случае, это по идее не относится к текущему вопросу.

Comment: @Vlad ладно, с Select'ом потом разберусь. а comparer в чистом виде и сгенерированный через codeDom работают ну очень медленно :(

Comment: @bmo: Ну, задавайте новый вопрос, разберёмся.

Answer (score 1):

Например есть класc Item с тремя полями. Если надо группировать объекты Item на основе разных наборов из этих полей, то в класс можно добавить метод ToCsv

```
class Item {
    public string F;
    public string I;
    public string O;
    public string ToCsv(bool f = true, bool i = true, bool o = true) {
        return String.Concat( 
           f ? this.F : "", "; ", 
           i ? this.I : "", "; ", 
           o ? this.O : "", "; ");
    }
}
```

---

```
var lst = new[] {
    new Item { F="ф1", I="и1", O="о1" },
    new Item { F="ф1", I="и2", O="о1" },
    new Item { F="ф2", I="и1", O="о2" },
    new Item { F="ф2", I="и2", O="о1" },
};

var b1 = true; b2 = false; b3 = true;
foreach (var g in lst.GroupBy(i => i.ToCsv(b1, b2, b3)))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" | ", g.Select(i => i.ToCsv())));
```

Результат

```
ф1; и1; о1; | ф1; и2; о1;
ф2; и1; о2;
ф2; и2; о1;
```

---

```
var b1 = false; b2 = false; b3 = true;   
foreach (var g in lst.GroupBy(i => i.ToCsv(b1, b2, b3)))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" | ", g.Select(i => i.ToCsv())));
```

Результат

```
ф1; и1; о1; | ф1; и2; о1; | ф2; и2; о1;
ф2; и1; о2;
```